# TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable i'm using scrapy and python 3.5

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a problem with my scrapyspider which uses the following code:

```
class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "craig"
    allowed_domains = ["craigslist.org"]
    start_urls = ["http://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/npo"]

    def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    titles = hxs.xpath("//span[@class='pl']")
    items = []
    for i in titles:
        item = CraigslistSampleItem()
        item["title"] = i.select("a/text()").extract()
        item["link"] = i.select("a/@href").extract()
        items.append(item)
    return items
```

This is my `items.py`

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class CraigslistSampleItem(Item):
    title = Field()
    link = Field()
```

When I run the spider with `scrapy crawl craig`, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
2017-03-07 10:13:44 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/npo>
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

How can I fix this? 
Thanks

Comment: Please fix your indentation. It is not clear what belongs to what.

Comment: I’m not sure how it would produce that error, but did you mean `for i in titles` rather than `range(titles)`?

Comment: yes before i post in here, i try with that but i have same error like that to.. :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I encountered a similar error after installing `scrapy` using `conda` which resulted in getting `scrapy` version 1.1 and `twisted` version 17.1.0.

I believe there is an incompatibility between `scrapy` versions less than 1.3.2 and `twisted` version 17.x. I was able to resolve it by downgrading `twisted` to version 16.x or upgrading `scrapy` to version 1.3.3.

Comment: I've submitted a Github issue here in case people are curious: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/2648